# Incremental database backup

Tags: php, mysql

Assuming I backed up my database last week, and I want to back up only the data that has been modified between last week and today, does MySQL offer any way to do that? 
 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you check the docs on [MySQL Backing Up](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html)? "MySQL supports incremental backups: You must start the server with the --log-bin option to enable binary logging ..."

Comment: I didn't know about its existence. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Details available from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Once I can make it work, I'll mark the question as answered.